# Consume a JSON on PHP using POST

Tags: php, json, http, fetch

I'm curently looking to consume on a php server a JSON object sent on a POST request. The Request Payload looks like:

```
'{"0":["item1",12,"23"],
"1":["item2",5,"34"],
"2":["item3",6,"4"],
"3":["item4",34,"6"],
"4":["item5",7,"4"]}'
```

However, I don't have any clue of how the $_POST variable would look like. I've already tried getting any value with i.e.

```
$_POST['0'][0];
$_POST[0][0];
(array) $_POST[0];
```

I've also tried with stating content-type: application/json and also without it. The main question is how the $_POST variable looks like when being a 2D array, since I can easily consume a json like: {"0":"a", "1":"s", "2":"d"}'.

Comment: **print_r($_POST);** will help you

Comment: @AksenP not when sending JSON it won't. JSON doesn't get passed into $_POST - see the link I posted above.

Comment: @ADyson, he/she might understand that the JSON isn't in the $_POST variable at all.

Comment: @AksenP that's what is explained in the duplicate question.

Answer (score -1):

To consume the raw payload in PHP (not a form or something else), you need to read the `php://input` stream:

```php
<?php

$payload = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($payload);

// now you can use your $data
```